# Incorrect results with COUNT function?

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm a beginner to SQL using ORACLE and have run into a few problems. I have a basic database with 4 tables (HOTEL,ROOM,BOOKING,GUEST) which are populated with data regarding price of rooms ext.

I have a written query that is supposed to find the numbers and names of guests who booked rooms in the price range between 230 and 350 dollars. Also show also how many times they booked such rooms. However, it doesn't seem to be giving me the correct output and I can't figure out why. Here's the query:

```
SELECT GUEST.GUEST_NAME "GUEST NAME",GUEST.GUEST_NO "GUEST NUMBER", 
COUNT(GUEST.GUEST_NO)     "NUMBER OF TIMES BOOKED"
FROM ROOM, GUEST, BOOKING
WHERE R_PRICE>=260
AND R_PRICE<=350
AND GUEST.GUEST_NO = BOOKING.GUEST_NO
AND ROOM.HOTEL_NO = BOOKING.HOTEL_NO
GROUP BY GUEST.GUEST_NO, GUEST.GUEST_NAME
ORDER BY "NUMBER OF TIMES BOOKED" ASC;
```

And the output:

```
Tina Duncan      G001    2
Jenny Freeman    G003    2
Martin Ferguson  G006    3
Paul Happy       G002    3
Steve Kirkwood   G005    3
```

Here is sample for tables:

ROOM:

```
   ROOM_NO HOTEL_NO R_TYPE
------- -------- ------ ---------
1       H100     S          220
2       H100     D          230
3       H100     F          310
1       H200     S          260
2       H200     D          170
3       H200     S          250
4       H200     F          180
5       H200     F          295
1       H300     D          200
2       H300     S          420
```

BOOKING:

```
DATE_FROM DATE_TO   ROOM_NO
--------- --------- -------
15-AUG-12 17-AUG-12 1
30-AUG-12 15-SEP-12 2
01-AUG-12 02-AUG-12 2
10-AUG-12 11-AUG-12 2
01-SEP-12 15-SEP-12 3
31-JUL-12 02-AUG-12 1
11-JUL-12 01-AUG-12 1
12-JUL-12 13-JUL-12 1
14-JUL-12 15-JUL-12 1
17-AUG-12 28-AUG-12 2
31-JUL-12 01-SEP-12 1
31-AUG-12 01-SEP-12 2
31-AUG-12 15-SEP-12 4
01-SEP-12 15-SEP-12 1
```

GUEST:

```
GUEST_NO G_NAME
-------- --------------------
G001     Tina Duncan
G002     Paul Happy
G003     Jenny Freeman
G012     Dianne Kelly
G005     Steve Kirkwood
G006     Martin Ferguson
G007     Vanessa Horton
Goo8     Bianca Begg
```

The output should be:

```
Paul Happy       G002    2
Jenny Freeman    G003    1
Steve Kirkwood   G005    1
Martin Ferguson      G006    1
Dianne Kelly     G012    1
```

Hopefully I have given you enough, i'd appreciate it heaps if i could get a little help. Thanks guys!

Comment: "However, it doesn't seem to be giving me the correct output" - and that is?

Comment: Please include a description of *how the results are wrong*, and preferably the input records for each three table that go to creating those results?

Comment: In the sampe data you've shown a Booking table without a GUEST_NO or HOTEL_NO field. However, you use these fields in your query - please can you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you haven't actually explained why you think your output is incorrect, but a few things spring immediately to mind.

Firstly, you will want to use the price stored in the Booking table, not the price in the Room table. Why? Well, the price in the Room table will change over time, whereas the price in the Booking table is the price the customer *actually paid*. **EDIT** I notice your Booking table does not store the price paid. It will need too!!

Secondly, you state the price range you are interested in is 230 - 350 dollars, but the query is 260 - 350 dollars.

Thirdly, if you want to count the number of bookings, then count the number of bookings. You are counting the guest ids.

I would suggest something like the following query:

```
SELECT GUEST.GUEST_NAME         "GUEST NAME",
       GUEST.GUEST_NO           "GUEST NUMBER", 
       COUNT(BOOKING.BOOKINGID) "NUMBER OF TIMES BOOKED"
FROM BOOKING JOIN
     GUEST ON GUEST.GUEST_NO = BOOKING.GUEST_NO
WHERE BOOKING.PRICE BETWEEN 230 AND 350
GROUP BY GUEST.GUEST_NO, GUEST.GUEST_NAME
ORDER BY "NUMBER OF TIMES BOOKED" ASC;
```

Comment: I have added much more including sample data if that helps

Answer (score 0):

This join is probably causing it:

```
AND ROOM.HOTEL_NO = BOOKING.HOTEL_NO
```

Because a hotel has many rooms, this join will generate a row (or +1 in the count) for each room in the hotel. Try adding this:

```
AND BOOKING.ROOM_NO = ROOM.ROOM_NO
```